# Traveling to Prague for a university exchange as a student from Canada (for 4 months) although I hold dual citizenship as an Italian citizen

Tags: visas, canada, italy, prague

I will be traveling to Prague in September for a university exchange as a student from Canada (for 4 months) although I hold dual citizenship as an Italian citizen (EU citizen). Due to my European citizenship (and passport), I understand that I do not need to get a student visa from the Czech embassy for my stay. Should I worry about not having a student visa? Can any one confirm this?

Also, if this is okay, what would be the best way to travel with my two passports?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello Gabriella, welcome to the site.  Questions about studying abroad belong on [Expatriates.SE], but I will confirm that as an Italian citizen you do not need a visa in any EU country for any purpose.  The linked duplicate should answer your question about how to travel with your two passports.  If not, please edit this question or leave a comment here to explain.

Comment: As an EU citizen, you do not need a visa. However, you must *register* your place of residence with the Czech municipal authorities. That's a difference -- a visa would be asking permission, the registration is notifying the authorities after you arrive. You should read up on your rights as an EU citizen, by the way. You can stay in the EU, you can make it easier for your family to travel, you can *vote* in some elections, you can get consular support from any EU embassy if there is none of your home country.